# MongoDB Aggregation count over a relation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've two collection, Buildings and Orders. A Building can have many Orders (1:N Relation).
I'm trying to achieve a "Top Ten Statistic"(Which Buildings have the most Orders) with the aggregation framework. 
My Problem is, how can i get the total Orders per Building? Is there a way to "mix" data from two collections in one aggregation?

Currently i'm doing something like this:

```
db.buildings.aggregate( [
                        { $group : _id : { street : "$street",
                                          city : "$city",
                                          orders_count : "$orders_count" }},
                        { $sort : { _id.orders_count : -1 }},
                        { $limit : 10}
                        ] );
```

But in this case the "orders_count" is  pre-calculated value. It works but is very inefficient and to slow for "live" aggregation.

Is there a way to count the related orders per building directly in the aggregation (im sure there is a way...)?

Many Thanks

Comment: aggregation can only be run on a single collection - why not query the orders collection for this information?  doesn't an order contain information about which building it's for?  if you add what order document looks like maybe we can suggest specific aggregation.

Comment: I've done this over the buildings because i need informations from this colllection too. The orders have a building_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how orders relate to buildings in your schema but if an order has a building id or name it references, just group by that:

```
db.orders.aggregate( { $group : { _id: "$buildingId",
                                  sum: {$sum:1}
                                }
                     },
                     /* $sort by sum:-1, $limit:10 like you already have */
)
```